# How to get table/field name in IdeaBlade 2012?

Tags: devforce

We are using IdeaBlade 2012 latest build in our project, in our helper function, it shows "table name"."field name" and user can add comments and save them in one table.
In EF, it can get dbContext.MetadataWorkspace to get metadata in edmx, but how can we get it in EntityMananger?

Comment: The EntityManager doesn't have access to database table and column names as it works with only the "conceptual" level of the model.  You have a couple of options if you want to do this in DevForce, though.  One is to customize the code generation template to include this information in your generated model as maybe custom properties or attributes.  Another is to construct the DbContext on your own in DF server-side code, such as a save interceptor.

Comment: Thanks! Option #1 works.

Comment: There's some info on the DevForce Resource Center to get started - http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/custom-code-generation-template.  If you need more you can open a support request via the IdeaBlade web site.

Answer (score 0):

As Kim Johnson mentioned in her comment, customizing the code generation can work really well for this.  We've done that in our app to add additional comments on each entity and field that includes the table/column name.  That helps the C# developers since we sometimes rename entities/properties and trying to map them back to the backend can be tricky.

However, more recently we've been wanted even more data out of the EF Model and have resorted to parsing the XML EDMX directly.  That gives us all the information we could want.  It even correlated the EDMX data with the DevForce metadata and even reflection data.

Here is the full code for that for anybody interested.  It's a lot of code but hopefully it's easy to follow.  And it likely does way more than most people would need.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for parsing the EDMX model, looking up DevForce metadata as well as C# reflection data and then combining it all
/// into organized data structures.
/// </summary>
public static class ModelDataExtractor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Information about a property/column from an EDMX.
    /// </summary>
    public class EdmxColumnInfo
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string SqlType { get; set; }
        public bool? Nullable { get; set; }
        public int? MaxLength { get; set; }
        public bool? FixedLength { get; set; }
        public bool? IsUnicode { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of information about a property.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExtraPropertyInfo
    {
        public PropertyInfo CSharpProperty { get; set; }
        public EntityProperty DevForceProperty { get; set; }
        public EdmxColumnInfo EdmxData { get; set; }
        public string TypeHierarchy { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts the data from the EDMX's embeded in the Business assembly.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<ExtraPropertyInfo> ExtractData()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(MyFavoriteEntity).Assembly;
        var all = from name in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
                  where name.EndsWith(".csdl") || name.EndsWith(".msl") || name.EndsWith(".ssdl")
                  let xml = XElement.Load(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
                  select new EdmxFragment(name.Replace(".csdl", "").Replace(".msl", "").Replace(".ssdl", ""), xml);

        return ExtractData(all.ToList());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts the data from the EDMX's in the given directory
    /// </summary>
    public static List<ExtraPropertyInfo> ExtractData(string dataModelPath)
    {
        return ExtractData(
            Directory.GetFiles(dataModelPath, "*.edmx")
                .Select(fileName => new EdmxFragment(fileName, XElement.Load(fileName)))
                .ToList());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the ability for multiple XElements to be treated as multiple fragments of the same logical EDMX.
    /// </summary>
    private class EdmxFragment
    {
        public EdmxFragment(string edmxName, XElement documentRoot)
        {
            EdmxName = edmxName;
            DocumentRoot = documentRoot;
        }

        public string EdmxName { get; private set; }
        public XElement DocumentRoot { get; private set; }
    }

    private static List<ExtraPropertyInfo> ExtractData(IList<EdmxFragment> edmxFragments)
    {
        //If we aren't given any fragments...well, nothing to do really
        if (edmxFragments.Count == 0)
        {
            return new List<ExtraPropertyInfo>();
        }

        //Derive the correct namespaces to use
        var ns = EdmxNamespaceHelper.DeriveNamespaces(edmxFragments[0].DocumentRoot);

        //First extract data out of the EDMXs 'sections'

        //Parse the SSDL data for each XML document
        var storageTypes = from fragment in edmxFragments
                           from entityType in fragment.DocumentRoot.Descendants(XName.Get("EntityType", ns.Ssdl))
                           from prop in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("Property", ns.Ssdl))
                           select new
                           {
                               TableName = entityType.GetString("Name"),
                               ColumnName = prop.GetString("Name"),
                               SqlType = prop.GetString("Type"),
                               Nullable = prop.GetBool("Nullable"),
                               MaxLength = prop.GetInt("MaxLength"),
                               fragment.EdmxName
                           };

        //Parse the CSDL data for each XML document
        var conceptualTypes = from fragment in edmxFragments
                              from entityType in fragment.DocumentRoot.Descendants(XName.Get("EntityType", ns.Csdl))
                              from prop in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("Property", ns.Csdl))
                              select new
                              {
                                  TypeName = entityType.GetString("Name"),
                                  PropertyName = prop.GetString("Name"),
                                  FixedLength = prop.GetBool("FixedLength"),
                                  IsUnicode = prop.GetBool("Unicode"),
                                  fragment.EdmxName
                              };

        //Parse the MSDL data for each XML document
        var mappings = from fragment in edmxFragments
                       from setMap in fragment.DocumentRoot.Descendants(XName.Get("EntitySetMapping", ns.Msdl))
                       let typeMap = setMap.Elements(XName.Get("EntityTypeMapping", ns.Msdl)).Single()
                       let mapFragment = typeMap.Elements(XName.Get("MappingFragment", ns.Msdl)).Single()
                       from prop in mapFragment.Elements(XName.Get("ScalarProperty", ns.Msdl))
                       let fullTypeName = typeMap.GetString("TypeName")
                       let typeName = fullTypeName.Substring(fullTypeName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1)
                       select new
                       {
                           TypeName = typeName,
                           TableName = mapFragment.GetString("StoreEntitySet"),
                           PropertyName = prop.GetString("Name"),
                           ColumnName = prop.GetString("ColumnName"),
                           fragment.EdmxName
                       };

        //Using the mapping info to join the Conceptual and Storage info
        var tempCombined = from storageInfo in storageTypes
                           join mapping in mappings
                               on new { storageInfo.ColumnName, storageInfo.TableName, storageInfo.EdmxName }
                               equals new { mapping.ColumnName, mapping.TableName, mapping.EdmxName }
                           join conceptualInfo in conceptualTypes
                               on new { mapping.PropertyName, mapping.TypeName, mapping.EdmxName } equals
                               new { conceptualInfo.PropertyName, conceptualInfo.TypeName, conceptualInfo.EdmxName }
                           select new
                           {
                               storageInfo,
                               mapping,
                               conceptualInfo
                           };
        //Flatten the information from the Conceptual and Storage info
        var edmxInfo = from c in tempCombined
                       select new
                       {
                           c.mapping.TypeName,
                           c.mapping.PropertyName,
                           ColumnInfo = new EdmxColumnInfo
                           {
                               TableName = c.storageInfo.TableName,
                               ColumnName = c.storageInfo.ColumnName,
                               SqlType = c.storageInfo.SqlType,
                               Nullable = c.storageInfo.Nullable,
                               MaxLength = c.storageInfo.MaxLength,
                               IsUnicode = c.conceptualInfo.IsUnicode,
                               FixedLength = c.conceptualInfo.FixedLength,
                           }
                       };

        //Build a dictionary for easy retrieval
        var fullEdmxData = edmxInfo.ToDictionary(d => d.TypeName + "." + d.PropertyName,
                                                 d => d.ColumnInfo);

        //Use Reflection and DevForce metadata to inspect the C# code
        var results =
            //Go through all the Types in assembly that 'my favorite entity' is in
            from cSharpType in typeof(MyFavorateEntity).Assembly.GetTypes()
            //Ignore abstract classes (the virtual entities probably)
            where !cSharpType.IsAbstract
            //Only process types that are Entities
            where cSharpType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity))
            //Build the class hierarchy as a string
            let hierarchy = GetAncestors(cSharpType).GetDelimitedString(" > ", t => t.Name)
            //Let all the C# properties (except the XYZProperty ones)
            let codeProperties = cSharpType.GetProperties()
            //Get the metadata from DevForce
            let modelMetadata = EntityMetadataStore.Instance.GetEntityMetadata(cSharpType)
            //Combine the C# data, the DevForce data and the EDMX data
            let combined = from codeProperty in codeProperties
                           join modelProperty in modelMetadata.EntityProperties
                               on codeProperty.Name equals modelProperty.Name into
                               matchedModelProperties
                           let singleMatchedModelProperty = matchedModelProperties.SingleOrDefault()
                           let typePropString = cSharpType.Name + "." + codeProperty.Name
                           let edmxData =
                               fullEdmxData.ContainsKey(typePropString)
                                   ? fullEdmxData[typePropString]
                                   : null
                           select new ExtraPropertyInfo
                           {
                               TypeHierarchy = hierarchy,
                               CSharpProperty = codeProperty,
                               DevForceProperty = singleMatchedModelProperty,
                               EdmxData = edmxData
                           }
            from c in combined
            select c;


        return results.ToList();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetAncestors(Type t)
    {
        var parent = t.BaseType;
        while (parent != typeof(Entity) && parent != null)
        {
            yield return parent;
            parent = parent.BaseType;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Helper class to dynamically determine the EDMX version (and therefore namespace names) of a particular EDMX file (or fragment)
/// </summary>
internal class EdmxNamespaceHelper
{
    public string Edmx { get; private set; }
    public string Csdl { get; private set; }
    public string Ssdl { get; private set; }
    public string Msdl { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Version 2 namespaces
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly EdmxNamespaceHelper V2 = new EdmxNamespaceHelper
    {
        Edmx = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx",
        Csdl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm",
        Ssdl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl",
        Msdl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs"
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Version 3 namespaces
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly EdmxNamespaceHelper V3 = new EdmxNamespaceHelper
    {
        Edmx = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx",
        Csdl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm",
        Ssdl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl",
        Msdl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs"
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Sees is this instance's namespaces seem to be valid for the given <see cref="XElement"/> root.
    /// </summary>
    private bool IsValid(XElement xmlRoot)
    {
        try
        {
            //See if the top element is the Runtime element (for .edmx files)
            return xmlRoot.Element(XName.Get("Runtime", Edmx)) != null ||
                //or if the root has a namespace of one of the individual sections (for fragments)
                   xmlRoot.Name.NamespaceName.In(Edmx, Csdl, Ssdl, Msdl);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines the correct <see cref="EdmxNamespaceHelper"/> for the given <see cref="XElement"/> root.
    /// </summary>
    public static EdmxNamespaceHelper DeriveNamespaces(XElement xmlRoot)
    {
        //Try V2 and V3.  If none of them seem to match, just error out.
        if (V2.IsValid(xmlRoot))
            return V2;
        if (V3.IsValid(xmlRoot))
            return V3;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine EDMX type of given XML Document");
    }
}
```